# OctoberCMS : Backend page not found

Tags: php, octobercms

I have two controllers in my backend, and both works on environnement.

But on production, both returns 404. I don't understand what is the problem. The navbar menu is displayed, the database is setup, and the components are workings.

The url is  `/devinx/exoticproducts/categories` and `/devinx/exoticproducts/products`. On dev, working, and on prod.: 404.

Note : the backend url is "backend" (default).

The source code of my plugin is avaible here : https://github.com/FelixINX/ExoticProducts

Comment: Is the backend url correct : domain.com/backend/devinx/exoticproducts/categories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it has to do with the fact that your repo is named in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), and probably you cloned it exactly like that to the production server.
However, October plugin and author namespace directories should always be completely in lower-case, i.e. `plugins/devinx/exoticproducts` and not `plugins/devinx/ExoticProducts` or `plugins/DevINX/exoticproducts`.

Maybe if your dev server runs in a Windows environment you have not noticed this before, since Windows does not differentiate between lower- and uppercase file and directory names.

Comment: Yep.. it was this. I am using Windows as the host of my Vagrant ScotchBox macine. The problem is that git clone make the directory CamelCase.

Comment: Great that this solved it. If you don't mind, would you accept and upvote my answer? (I need the reputation score, in order to help get the [OctoberCMS proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms) off the ground. We need at least 71 more people among the committers with rep 200 or more in other networks to make this go into beta. :P)

Comment: Sure! Forgot about that. I hope we get the octobercms beta soon!

Comment: Thanks! Yay, I hope so, too!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i solved this by turning back on     'debug' => true
in app.php